# How to include a server in an android studio project?

Tags: android, server, sip

How would one incorporate a server into an android studio project? I Saw a video on YouTube where the programmer incorporated the tomcat server to an Eclipse project. If you can do it in Eclipse why not in Studio? Any suggestions. 
Also, is it possible to communicate via WiFip2p while streaming live video from one cellphone to another one? Thereby, bypassing A SIP stack implementation.

thank you

Comment: Search on _Google_. i dont think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can use github and android studio can sync your projects